# Differential equations finding an expression

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

A spark from a firework is moving in a straight line at a speed which is inversely proportional to the square of the distance which the spark has travelled from the firework. Find and expression for the speed (i.e. the rate of change of distance travelled) of the spark.

I just started the differential equations chapter and I'm really not understanding it, can someone help me get going please?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you must write mathematically your statement.

The speed will be $dx/dt$ because it's moving in a straight line (the $x$-axis) and the distance which the spark has travelled is denoted by $x$. If we "translate" the whole statement,
\begin{equation}
\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{k}{x^2},
\end{equation}
where $k$ is the constant of proportion.

Now, you must only solve this equation by separation of variables. (Try it youself and don't continue reading if you want to practice)

\begin{equation}
\int_0^x x^2 dx = \int_0^t kdt \implies \left.\frac{x^3}{3}\right|_{0}^x = \left. kt\right|_0^t \implies x = \sqrt[3]{3kt}
\end{equation}
Here I assumed that the initial position (when $t = 0$) is $x = 0$.

Comment: I think you forgot to read this part: "inversely proportional to the **square** of the distance"

Comment: Changed! Thank you :)

Comment: You're welcome. Even though the question did not ask to solve the differential equation, I think it can help expand the OP's knowledge. Therefore, I added an upvote. (+1)

Answer (score 0):

Let's call the distance $x$. Note that instantaneous speed is the infinitesimal change of distance over the infinitesimal change in time. Mathematically, this can be written as:
$$\frac{dx}{dt}$$
Now, note that it is **inversely proportional to the square of the distance** $x$. Try writing this in mathematical notation. You should be looking for something like:
$$\frac{dx}{dt}\propto \cdots$$
One may convert this to an equality by introducing the constant of proportionality $k$.
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=k\cdot \dots$$